# how to automatically reload the page on session timeout

Tags: php, session

I want to automatically unset session variables and reload index.php when session gets timedout in php.How to achieve this?

```
<?php
session_start();

?>
<html>
//html code 
</html>
```

Comment: can you please elaborate how to do that?

Comment: Well, if you want to unset the session on the timeout, you need to implement some javascript i guess that calls a certain PHP file maybe? This php file destroys the session and redirects to index.php or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Set a JavaScript timer and then use this if you want the session to be destroyed:

```
<?php
session_destroy();

header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads, you'll want to determine how much time is left in the session and, at that point, set a Javascript timer to redirect the user to a "logout" that calls `session_destroy()` and then redirects back to the (logged out) home page.

**JavaScript**

```
//If there is one minute left for the session to expire... 
//The actual value that should go where "60000" is should 
//be calculated by PHP that renders this code.

setTimeout(function(){
    window.location='doLogout.php';
}, 60000);
```

**PHP (doLogout.php)**

```
<?php
   session_destroy();
   header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would refresh page after timeout.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: Doesn't work on a lot of browsers anymore due to security reasons

Comment: Didn't know. Any source to which browsers do not support it?

Comment: On my cell phone right now but IE doesnt support it and I believe firefox doesn't either